# How to find whether appium driver is quit or active

Tags: java, appium

I am using three drivers like
AppiumDriver driver, driver1, driver2;

---

Each driver has it own capabilities and launch three different apps one after another quiting the old driver

---

Now if test case is failed at any instance while running, how to find which driver is currently Active

Comment: Will 'driver.Capabilities' be enough for you?

Comment: Yes, driver Capabilities are enough for launching apps and testing. Please let me know if my answer is not related to you question Thank You..

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten into a habit of extending my WebDriver classes so that I can piggy-back on top of web-driver specific methods, set booleans, mark attributes as needed, etc etc.

If you want to personally keep track of the state of an appium-driver instance that is Android driven:

```
public class MyAppiumDriver extends AndroidDriver<WebElement> {
    boolean active;

    public MyAppiumDriver(URL url, Capabilities capabilities) {
        super(url, capabiliites);
        active = true;
    }

    public void quit() {
        active = false;
        super.quit();
    }

    public boolean isActive() {
        return active;
    }
}
```

Then in your tests, you can instantiate and use in this manner:

```
MyAppiumDriver driver = new MyAppiumDriver();
System.out.println("Is driver active? " + driver.isActive());

driver.quit();
System.out.println("Is driver active? " + driver.isActive());
```